# Разложение звукового сигнала в MATLAB с помощью преобразования Фурье

Tags: matlab

У меня имеются звуковые файлы в формате *.wav*.
Как в MATLAB их правильно разложить на гармонические составляющие c помощью преобразования Фурье?

Comment: Когда-то в универе были лабки по матлабу. Там в инструкциях хорошо описано.

Comment: А чем вам топ-10 из гугла не нравится? Например это https://habrahabr.ru/post/112068/?

Comment: А по подробней, пожалуйста, расскажете?

Comment: я просто ещё не знаю сколько у меня синусоид в сигнале будет и какие частоты они имеют, у меня пока есть сигнал во временной области и я не могу понять как правильно его перевести в частотную область. Звук записан с частотой дискретизации 44100 Гц и в 16 бит

Comment: Сигнал имеет длительность 10 секунд